# Directing an agent on a specific path (Netlogo)

Tags: netlogo

there is a question that I want to ask that is when I trying to type this code, I got the error that is

> The > operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a number and a list.

What I want to ask is how can I fix this, the false happen at this line on the code :

> if pri-lev > [pri-lev] of oppoint1 and pri-lev > [pri-lev] of oppoint2

I tried to change it into "cars-on" or "cars with" but they are all useless. I also try to find on the Netlogo dictionary but I found no results on the code for directing an agent on a specific path.
What I am trying to do here is when an agent comes to a specific section, it will check if any agents listed as "oppoint1"; "oppoint2"; "oppoint3"; "oppoint4" and then compare a value call pri-lev to others value for setting its decision on keeping on moving or stopping and wait for others.
These are the part of my code:

```
ask cars
[
  let oppoint1 (cars-at (xcor + 2) (ycor + 2))
  let oppoint2 (cars-at (xcor - 1) (ycor + 1))
  let oppoint3 (cars-at (xcor - 2) (ycor + 1))
  let oppoint4 (cars-at (xcor - 3) (ycor + 1))
  ifelse oppoint1 != nobody and oppoint2 != nobody
  [
    if pri-lev > [pri-lev] of oppoint1 and pri-lev > [pri-lev] of oppoint2
      [
        set pri-lev 4
        speed-up
      ]
  ]
  [
    if oppoint2 = nobody and oppoint3 = nobody and oppoint4 = nobody
    [
      set speed 1
      fd speed
      if turning = "Rtrue"
      [
        set heading heading + 90
        speed-up
      ]
    ] 
  ]
]
```

Sincerely, Minh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the reason you are getting this error is that you are comparing the attribute of one (the current car) to the attributes of many (the oppoint agent-sets). Your code now says something like "If my privilege is greater than the privilege of that group, do this thing..." The problem is that `[pri-lev] of oppoint1` returns a list of the `pri-lev` of all members of the `oppoint1` agentset, like `[ 10 12 13 24 ]`, and Netlogo won't automatically iterate over that list and compare each item to the attribute of the asking turtle.

There are several ways to deal with this. For example, you could make sure that you only ever compare two turtles- maybe by making sure that you only ever have one turtle per patch at a given time. If you are going to potentially compare one agent to an agent-set, you can use the `any?` primitive to check if any members of the group you're looking at satisfy your conditional statement. For example, given this setup:

```
turtles-own [
  pri-lev
]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 10 [
    set pri-lev 1 + random 10
  ]
end
```

You can ask `one-of` your turtles to check if `not any?` of the turtles on the current patch have a higher `pri-lev` than the asking turtle. If none of them do, the current turtle will move forward. Otherwise, it will print that there is another turtle with a higher `pri-lev` on the current patch.

```
to compare-with

  ask one-of turtles [
    let other-turtles other turtles-here 
    ifelse not any? other-turtles with [ pri-lev > [pri-lev] of myself ] [
      fd 1
    ]
    [ 
      print ("A turtle here has a higher pri-lev than I do." )
    ]
  ]
  tick

end
```

Comment: Dear Luke, thank you for the comment, however, I dont want to do this globally since when it check globally, there always have some agents with higher priority than the current one, what I want the agent check is the agents among a specific region only. For example: the agent currently at (6,10); I want him to check on 3 others location (5,11); (7,12) and (5,9) only but not checking on, in example, (9,11) or (11,12), so on. Is there anyway specifies them? Or should I form a group from those location and then checking among members in a group?

Comment: In my example above, the turtles only check the patch that they are **currently** on (`turtles-here` is the primitive that does that) - not all patches/globally. Try it in a new file, it's all the code needed. The point I was trying to make is that you cannot compare one agent to many in the way that you were since you were comparing a variable of one agent to a list of variables of an agentset. All you have to do is change the `let` statement in my example above to suit your model specifically (eg. instead of the `other-turtles` agent-set I defined, substitute in your "oppoint" agentsets).